# Como hacerlo en MySql?

Tags: php, mysqli

Veran,esta vez no tengo código,ni tampoco quiero que me den código,sino simplemente la idea.

Tengo un sistema de posts al que quiero añadirle un botón para darle puntos(al post seleccionado).Bien.

Pero como hago para que esos mismos puntos que yo de al post se le acumulen al usuario que posteo el post. Algo así como un recipiente.

Acaso tengo que usar dos sentencia sql?Una para que inserte los puntos en la campo del post en la Bd y otra que lo inserte en el acumulado del usuario??

Para fácil de entender:

```
                     ****Tabla usuario****
       ----   --------   ------     ---------
       Id     Nombre     Apellidos  Acumulado
       ----  -------    ---------   ---------
         1    Luis        Tavarez     100




                     ****Tabla posts****
       ----    ----------      --------     ---------     ---------
      Id_post   Id_usuario     Titulo       Contenido       Votos
       ----        -------    ---------     ---------      -------
        2            1         Saludos     Buenos días
```

Como pueden ver el campo votos esta en cero,porque todavía no se ha asignado nada.
Pero si yo asigno,por ejemplo "10" puntos a ese post,quedaría así:

```
                             **Tabla posts**
       ----    ----------      --------     ---------     ---------
      Id_post   Id_usuario     Titulo       Contenido       Votos
       ----        -------    ---------     ---------      -------
        2            1         Saludos     Buenos días       10
```

Entonces,el acumulado en la tabla usuario que tiene "100" puntos  acumulados sumaria "10" puntos mas.y quedaria asi:

```
                    ****Tabla usuario****
       ----   --------   ------     ---------
       Id     Nombre     Apellidos  Acumulado
       ----  -------    ---------   ---------
         1    Luis        Tavarez     110
```

En pocas palabras todos los puntos que se les den a mis post se acumulan en el campo "Acumulado" de la tabla "usuario".

Answer (score 5):

> Usar acumuladores (o recipientes) en bases de datos
>   nunca es una buena idea a menos que puedan ser "auditables". Es decir,
>   que se pueda verificar de alguna que el valor almacenado es correcto.

Con esto en mente, data la estructura de datos que planteas, yo me preguntaría lo siguiente:

- Puedo saber quienes votaron?
- Puedo saber cuanto puntos le dio?
- Puedo evitar que un mismo usuario vote infinitas veces un mismo post?
- Quiero poder generar estadísticas de votos?

Ahora, en respuesta a las preguntas

> Acaso tengo que usar dos sentencia sql?Una para que inserte los puntos en la campo del post en la Bd y otra que lo inserte en el acumulado del usuario??

Yo te sugiero hacer una *tabla de detale*.

Viendo que ya tenes las tablas *usuarios y posts*, deberías crear una tercer tabla **"posts_votos"**

```
// TABLA posts_votos
|-------|----------|------|-----------|
|id_post|id_usuario|puntos|fecha      |
|-------|----------|------|-----------|
|1      |1         |10    |2016-10-26 |
|-------|----------|------|-----------|
```

Esta tabla permite:

- **Registrar / Guardar**: voto de un usuario sobre un post.

  ```php
  $postId = 1;
  $idUsuario = 1;
  $puntos = 1;
  $query = 'INSER INTO posts_votos (id_post, id_usuario, puntos)
      VALUES ('.$postId.', '.$idUsuario.', '.$puntos.')';
  ```
- **Controlar / Verificar**: si un usuario ya voto un post.

  ```php
  $postId = 1;
  $idUsuario = 1;
  $query = 'SELECT * 
      FROM posts_votos
      WHERE id_post = '.$postId.' AND id_usuario = '.$idUsuario;
  ```
- **Informar / Consultar**:

  - Cuantos votos y puntos tiene un posts.

  ```
  $postId = 1;
  $query = 'SELECT SUM(puntos) AS puntosTotal,
        COUNT(puntos) AS votosTotal
      FROM posts_votos
      WHERE id_post = '.$postId;
  ```

  - Cuantos votos y puntos hizo un usuario.

  ```
  $idUsuario = 1;
  $query = 'SELECT SUM(puntos) AS puntosTotal,
        COUNT(puntos) AS votosTotal
      FROM posts_votos
      WHERE id_usuario = '.$idUsuario;
  ```

  - Cuantos votos y puntos tiene el autor del post.

  ```
  $idAutor = 1;
  $query = 'SELECT SUM(puntos) AS puntosTotal,
        COUNT(puntos) AS votosTotal
      FROM posts_votos
      WHERE id_posts IN (
        SELECT id_post 
        FROM posts
        WHERE id_autor = '.$idAutor.'
      )';
  ```

  - También, de ser necesario, se puede saber cuantos votos recibió un post/autor en el ultimo mes y/o cuantos votos dio un usuario.

  ```
  $idAutor = 1;
  $query = 'SELECT SUM(puntos) AS puntosTotal,
        COUNT(puntos) AS votosTotal
      FROM posts_votos
      WHERE fecha BETWEEN "2016-10-01" AND "2016-10-31"
      AND id_posts IN (
        SELECT id_post 
        FROM posts
        WHERE id_autor = '.$idAutor.'
      )';
  ```

> pero si yo borro ese post se van a borrar todos los puntos,y no quiero que se borren ninguno,sino que esos puntos se queden acumulado

Con esta tabla, nunca perderás esa info.

Comment: Amigo,te explicare mejor:

Comment: He actualizado mi respuesta.

Comment: Amigo.Una pregunta....Observando esos codigos sql,me doy cuenta que si borro un post,se queda un rastro de que hubo un post que ya no existe.Osea si borro el post con id "1" de la tabla "posts",en la tabla "post_votos"se queda grabado el id  de ese post con sus puntos recibidos..Porque asi???Quiero que si borro ese post no quede nada de ese post en ninguna tabla.Y si explicate algo arriba acerca de recipientes.Pero yo no identificar esos puntos acumulados.

Comment: Es lógico que no quieras dejar `residuos` en la DB. Para solucionar este tipo de *"problemas"* puedes: implementar `triggers` o codigo con la lógica tras la eliminación de un `post` para `archivar` votos o eliminarlos o lo que consideres pertinente.

Comment: Lo que pasa es que después de tener esos puntos acumulados,darles utilidad también.¿Como?Que también yo pueda con esos puntos darles votos a los  posts de los demás usuarios.No se si entiendan.Este es un ejemplo:::Publico algo,instantáneamente recibo 5 0 10 puntos.los cuales se van sumando en el acumulado y de esos mismos puedo puntuar posts ajenos a los mios.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que lo quieres hacer es el `esquema` de una `base de datos` con dos `tablas`, algo más o menos así:

```
// TABLA posts
|-------|----------|------|----|
|id_post|id_usuario|puntos|post|
|-------|----------|------|----|
|1      |1         |10    |POST|
|-------|----------|------|----|

// TABLA usuarios
|----------|-------|
|id_usuario|usuario|
|----------|-------|
|1         |LUIS   |
|----------|-------|
```

Y para actualizar los `puntos` en dicho `post` respecto al `usuario` (que es como entiendo lo quieres) sería con un simple `query`:

```
UPDATE posts SET puntos = 20 WHERE id_usuario = 1;
```

Comment: pero si yo borro ese post se van a borrar todos los puntos,y no quiero que se borren ninguno,sino que esos puntos se queden acumulado en un campo llamado ""puntos"" en la tabla "usuarios"

Comment: Entonces tu mismo te estás respondiendo, pasa el campo `puntos` a la tabla `usuarios` y el `query` quedaría así: `UPDATE usuarios SET puntos = 20 WHERE id_usuario = 1`;

Comment: No entiendo.Como que pase el campo?Se supone que la tabla ""usuarios" lleva un campo""puntos" al igual que la tabla "posts".

Answer (score 3):

puedes hacer una suma en la consulta, no tienes que almacenarlo en la base de datos aparte, creo que iría algo así

```
SELECT SUM(points) as puntos FROM post WHERE user_id = 1
```

también podrías aplicarle un promedio, algo así como calificación del usuario, que los usuarios califiquen los post con estrellas (1 a 5 estrellas) y puedes sacar un promedio a partir de las estrellas otorgadas al post entre los post que ha tenido ese usuario

Answer (score 1):

Lo que tu pides sí se hace con el diseño que has puesto,

> Acaso tengo que usar dos sentencia sql?

Puedes hacer dos consultas o dentro de la tabla post crear un trigger que te incremente el campo Acumulado

Pero como bien ha dicho Marcos, de esta forma esta perdiendo todo tipo de trazabilidad, de quien, cuando y como han llegado esos puntos ahí.

Planteate poner un campo `activo` o `visible` en la tabla posts de forma que los posts no los borres, simplemente los ocultas al usuario de esta forma tienes:

- trazabilidad de quien ha hecho cada cosa
- si un post realmente quieres que no cuente para votación porque no cumple unos requisitos lo puedes eliminar definitivamente.
- Los posts "eliminados" siguen sumando

Comment: No se usar eso de trigger.Tratare de  usar los demas ejemplos de abajo.Ahh no necesito saber quien me dio votos hablando del acumulado,pero si necesito saber quien me los dio en los posts.Porque si ya estan acumulado,eso es todo lo que necesito. Tener esos puntos y ya